# "accueilli des plus chaleureusement"

Tags: grammaire, adverbes

Issu du livre *Bête noire* d'Éric Dupond-Moretti, page 38 :

> Je suis allé consulter le dossier chez le juge d'instruction qui, une fois n'est pas coutume, m'a accueilli des plus chaleureusement.

Ce "m'a accueilli des plus chaleureusement" ne me semble pas correct, alors que je comprends bien le sens. À la place, j'écrirais

> [...], m'a accueilli *d'une façon des plus chaleureuses*

ou bien

> [...], m'a accueilli *le plus chaleureusement*

mais "des plus" + adverbe me semble maladroit.

Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est une tournure correcte et relativement courante, bien que soutenue. Le sens est bien celui que tu indiques (superlatif).

> *À l'Opéra. Le beau ténor Muratore vient d'effectuer sa rentrée dans* Faust, *où il a été naturellement accueilli **des plus chaleureusement**.*
> Le ménestrel, 1833.

***Des plus*** est plus souvent suivi d'un adjectif et signifie alors *très* (sans accord) ou *parmi les plus* (avec accord). Suivi d'un adverbe, le seul sens possible est *très* et il n'y a bien sûr pas d'accord, un adverbe étant invariable.

Voici une citation plus récente contenant *des plus + adverbe* :

> *La seule exception, vous l’avez saisie au passage, concerne le tout qui précède un adjectif féminin commençant par une consonne ou par un « h » aspiré. On peut en effet se demander pourquoi la grammaire, qui nous oblige à écrire, **des plus logiquement**, « la réalisatrice était tout étonnée », nous impose parallèlement « la réalisatrice était toute surprise ».*
> [Bruno Dewaele](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_Dewaele), [*Par mots et par vaux*](http://www.parmotsetparvaux.fr/afpa/afpa5.html).

Référence: *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §993, p 1442

> g) **Des plus**, originairement superlatif relatif (Une vie des plus nobles = ... parmi les plus nobles vies), sert simplement à exprimer un haut degré, ce que montrent les faits suivants.
>
> - L'adjectif qui suit est souvent traité, non comme faisant partie
>   d'un syntagme prépositionnel pluriel, mais comme un adjectif
>   attribut s'accordant avec son sujet ou comme une épithète
>   s'accordant avec le nom qui précède des plus.
>   [...]
>   Le pluriel reste cependant très fréquent
>   [...]
> - Quand des plus se rapporte à un pronom neutre ou à un infinitif, il ne peut s'analyser comme équivalent de **parmi les plus**
>   (et impliquer l'ellipse d'un nom exprimé auparavant)
> - **Des plus** est joint à un adverbe, l'ensemble se rapportant à un verbe (ce qui rend impossible l'ellipse dont nous parlons ci-dessus ainsi que toute variabilité) :
>
>   *Nous l'avons saisi **DES PLUS TARD*** (MUSSET, Contes, Lettres de
>   Dupuis et Cotonet, II). *— Si je pensais à ce que vous dictez, j'écrirais **DES PLUS MAL*** (VALÉRY, « Mon Faust », Lust, I, 1).

Comment: Ça vaut le coup de donner un lien: − Des plus + adj., littér., superl. abs. Parmi les plus, très. Un personnage secondaire et des plus effacés (Milosz, Amour. init., 1910, p.7).

Comment: @Lambie *Chaleureusement* n'est pas un adjectif.

Comment: **Des plus + adj., littér., superl. abs. Parmi les plus, très**. **Très chaleureusement**.

Comment: @Lambie L'écrire en gras n'y changera rien, *chaleureusement* est un adverbe, pas un adjectif. Le TLFI n'aborde pas ce cas et c'est pour ça que je ne l'ai pas cité.

Comment: D'ailleurs, *parmi les plus chaleureusement* ne veut rien dire.

Comment: C'est la seule définition que j'ai trouvé. T'en a une autre?? Si cela veut dire "très, cela marcherait avec un adjectif ou avec un adverbe. Tu le dis: "Suivi d'un adverbe, le seul sens possible est très". Alors, il faut pas citer le dico? Il n'a pas d'autre saint à qui se vouer dans des cas comme celui-ci.

Comment: @Lambie Citer un dictionnaire qui dit ce que l'OP sait déjà me semble superflu. Je préfère chercher des sources relatives à sa question qui concerne la présence d'un adverbe à cet endroit.

Comment: Ah bon? Je ne vois pas oú il dit que cela veut dire "très".

Comment: @Lambie Bon, te voilà j'en suis sûr satisfaite. J'ai trouvé une référence qui concerne le sujet de la question, *des plus + adverbe*.

Answer (score 2):

On trouve cette forme assez souvent et dans le monde des personnes très instruites. On doit donc considérer cet usage comme étant correct. Il est possible de consulter plus d'exemples que ceux fournis ci-dessous à la page suivante : « [des plus chaleureusement, exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22des%20plus%20chaleureusement%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ». Il ne faudra pas confondre dans la lecture de ces exemples additionnels certains cas d'utilisation de cette construction qui ne correspondent pas aux cinq ci-dessous.

([réf. 1, 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_laboratoire_belge_du_droit_internatio/vmRwDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&pg=PT57&printsec=frontcover)) Je remercie des plus chaleureusement l'Académie royale de Belgique pour avoir accepté de publier ce travail dans sa collection des Mémoires

([réf. 2, 2020](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Chroniques_de_l_%C3%A9trange_Tome_1/QVIAEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&pg=PT122&printsec=frontcover)) Le fils des villageois, accueilli dans la belle-famille, était traité des plus chaleureusement par toute la maisonnée.

([réf. 3, 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Prince_Princesse_Tome_II/KsRaDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&pg=PA64&printsec=frontcover)) Trois jours plus tard, ils revinrent et furent accueillis des plus chaleureusement par le Carré Royal, et les gens de la ville, mais Rachel n'était pas là

([réf. 4, 2011](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Treize_T2/L6QXEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&pg=PA20&printsec=frontcover)) S'il l'avait vu, le commerçant, normalement si courtois, aurait salué l'étranger des plus chaleureusement.

([réf. 5, 2009](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bulletin_de_la_Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_pr%C3%A9historique/cItOAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&dq=%22des+plus+chaleureusement%22&printsec=frontcover)) Je remercie enfin des plus chaleureusement M. Christensen , B. Valentin , A. Averbouh , C. Normand , P. Chambon , D. Liolios , L. Klaric

Comme déjà indiqué plus haut, on trouve des cas d'utilisation comme les suivant qui ne sont pas du même type parce que le verbe devient un nom (pronom) et qu'un  participe passé suit « chaleureusement » ou parce que le nom disparait tout simplement et que l'adjectif reste.

- que les sodats appelaient le dieu Mars , - quelques pages des plus chaleureusement senties de leur livre
- le vendredi 22 décembre , une conférence des plus intéressante et des plus chaleureusement applaudie
- Il fut un des plus chaleureusement applaudis.
- immortalisé par Wanda Jackson à de pétillants sirops country, la voix de Pearl s'affirme comme l'une des plus chaleureusement versatile du moment.

> - pages, conférence, un, l'une
> - senties, applaudie, applaudis, versatile

La différence essentielle réside en la présence d'un nom duquel le groupe prépositionnel « des plus chaleureusement » est le complément ; « des plus chaleureusement », dans ces cas-là doit être compris comme « de les plus chaleureusement », ou sans ellipse, « de ceux qui sont les plus chaleureusement (applaudis, accueillis, fêtés, …) » ; on reconnait donc une syntaxe pour ainsi dire « standard ».

Il est évident qu'un glissement s'est produit et que les utilisateurs du langage ont commencé à ne plus mentionner un nom (ou pronom), mais à le remplacer par un verbe qui est le verbe correspondant à l'adjectif.

- senties → des pages ont été senties des plus chaleureusement
- applaudie  → une conférence a été applaudie des plus chaleureusement
- applaudi → on l'a applaudi des plus chaleureusement
- versatile → s'affirme comme versatile des plus chaleureusement

De ce fait on n'analyse plus « des plus chaleureusement » dans les « constructions sans nom » parce que  cette expression est considérée omme  idiomatique.

Je pense donc que votre intuition est justifiée, si on ne tient pas compte du fait que l'usage par glissement est idiomatique, alors il y a une erreur de syntaxe.

On n'est pas forcé d'utiliser cette forme idiomatique, qui pour le lecteur à l'esprit analytique est propre à laisser une impression de vide et d'impropriété. Néanmoins, l'option de remplacement envisagée n'est pas correct. Il faut ajouter un complément du superlatif relatif (le plus + adj. + **de**). ([LE FRANÇAIS POUR TOUS](https://www.lefrancaispourtous.com/superlatifs.htm)) Il y a un complément qui est usuel dans la littérature, et qui donne lieu à une expression quasi figée, c'est le mot  « monde » : « le plus chaleureusement du monde ». Cependant, c'est une expression que les gens (instruits) n'utilisent pas trop dans le parler de tous les jours. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+plus+chaleureusement+du+monde&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20chaleureusement%20du%20monde%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20plus%20chaleureusement%20du%20monde%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Je trouve aussi que c’est bizarre.
J’aurais plutôt écrit : m’a réservé un accueil des plus chaleureux.